# Newly added entity is not showed correctly in my foreach knockout loop

Tags: entity-framework, knockout.js, breeze, durandal

I work on an asp.net mvc project with Breeze.

I have a page where I display details about a transport and list linked transports in a table below it.

Consider the following entities:

```
public class Transport
{
    [Key]
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string TransportNumber { get; set; }
    public string Description { get; set; }
    public virtual List<LinkedTransport> LinkedTransports { get; set; }
    ...
}

public class LinkedTransport
{
    [Key, Column(Order = 0)]
    public int TransportId { get; set; }
    [Key, Column(Order = 1)]
    public int TransportRelatedId { get; set; }

    public virtual Transport Transport { get; set; }
    public virtual Transport TransportRelated { get; set; }
}
```

So these 2 entities allows me to define my transports and (for each) linked transports.

First, I load my (main) transport into an observable named `transport`:

```
var query = entityQuery.from('Transports')
                       .where('id', '==', transportId)
                       .expand("LinkedTransports.transportRelated");
query = query.using(breeze.FetchStrategy.FromServer);
```

Please pay attention to the `expand` where I retrieve also the linked transports.

Now I have the following code for showing my transport and linked transports:

```
<div data-bind="with: transport()">
    <input type="text" data-bind="text: transportNumber"></input>
    <input type="text" data-bind="value: description"></input>       
    ...
    <table data-bind="foreach: linkedTransports">
        <tr>
            <td data-bind="text: transportRelated().transportNumber()"></td>
            <td data-bind="text: transportRelated().description()"></td>
        </tr> 
    </table>
</div>
```

So far, so good. I can display my main transport informations and also linked transports informations. Now I need to let the user add some linked transports. So I have the following code:

```
var createLinkedTransport = function (transpId, transpRelatedId) {

    var initialValues = ({
        transportId: transpId,
        transportRelatedId: transpRelatedId
    });

    manager.createEntity(entityNames.linkedTransport, initialValues);
};
```

At runtime, when I call this function, I can add a linked transport to my (main) transport.

**My problem:** the added element is not correctly showed in my foreach knockout loop. I see that a new row is added to the table but this one is empty. I think the problem is because I don't `expand` any information on my newly added element but I don't know how to proceed.

Any idea how to proceed?

---

UPDATE

To be clear, when I add a linkedTransport to my transport, immediately after the add (and without reloading the page) I cannot read properties of the targetted (*) linkedTransport. BUT if I saveChanges AND reload my page, THEN I can read properties of the targetted linkedTransport.

When I say 'the targetted linkedTransport' I mean the transport which is referenced by my TransportRelatedId (>> `public virtual Transport TransportRelated`).

So If I add the linkedTransport **#123** to the transport **#456** THEN immediately (without reloading the page) I cannot display the `Description` property of the #123.

```
<div data-bind="with: transport()">
    ...
    <div data-bind="foreach: linkedTransports">
        <label data-bind="text: transportRelated().description()"></label>
    </div>
</div>
```

Hope I'm clear.

---

UPDATE 2

As suggested by Ward, I set a breakpoint immediately after adding the `linkedTransports` and check the `transport().linkedTransports()`. Below is the results:

[image]

- transport().linkedTransports()[0].transport() >> the properties are there
- transport().linkedTransports()[0].transportId() >> 1
- transport().linkedTransports()[0].transportNumber >> '123456' ("dummy" property, does not help)
- transport().linkedTransports()[0].transportRelated() >> null
- transport().linkedTransports()[0].transportRelatedId() >> 5 (the id of the linkedTransport)

So my problem is that the `transportRelated()` is null.

---

UPDATE 3

Finally I got it working. It is important to have the added (referenced) element in cache when it is added. For my case I do something like:

```
ctxTransport.getTransportById(5, obs);
ctxTransport.createLinkedTransport(1, 5);
```

So before calling the `createLinkedTransport` I call the `getTransportById` with the 5th id (the id of the linkedTransport).

Anothing important thing is how we display the linkedTransports on our page:

```
<div data-bind="foreach: linkedTransports">                        
    <span class="input-control text">
        <!-- ko with: transportRelated -->
        <a href="#" class="fg-color-darken" data-bind="attr: { href: '#/generalTransport/' + id(), title: 'Cliquez pour ouvrir ce transport' }, text: transportNumber"></a>
        <!-- /ko -->
        <i class="icon-remove btn" data-bind="click: $root.removeLinkedTransport" style="cursor:pointer;"/>
    </span>
</div>
```

Pay attention to the `ko with: transportRelated` followed by `<a href="#" data-bind="text: id()"`. At first I do wrong `<a href="#" data-bind="text: transportRelated().id()"`. We cannot proceed like that.

Comment: Are the parens around `initialValues` initializer really there? Those looks superfluous.

Comment: What do you mean? Sorry I didn't understand you. The parents, you mean the complete entity? Superfluous?

Comment: No, the parenthases that come after `initialValues =`, the ones that surround the curly braces. You only need the curly braces to declare an object literal.

Comment: Ok but that's not the origin of the problem.

Comment: No, it's irrelevant. I was just commenting =)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

### Updated Answer

The short of it: the related transport entity wasn't showing up because it was not in cache.

Mr. B had the ID of the related entity and used that id while creating the new transport-link entity. But that id referred to an entity which is not in cache. Therefore, the navigation property to the related transport entity returned ... null.

Breeze navigation properties do not lazy load (as a server-side ORM such as EF might do). You have to ensure that the referenced entities are in cache.

This is a design choice, not an omission. In our experience, lazy loading leads to misuse which leads to performance problems that are blamed on the framework. We decided to bypass this particular hassle .. at least for now.

See the comments for more information.

Perhaps as important ... see how we diagnosed the problem. Good lessons learned there.

### Original "wrong" Answer

[This answer turned out to be "wrong" but it lead to the "right" answer. Preserved for continuity.]

How is EF treating your LinkedTransport entity? It looks like it lacks data properties of its own; it only has foreign keys to related entities. Could it be that EF regards LinkedTransport as the junction table of a many-to-many association.

As you probably know, Breeze does not (yet ... and won't soon) support many to many. What happens if you give this table a data property ... even a dummy data property such as a Boolean? That will force EF to treat it as its own entity type ... with a compound key. The OrderDetail in Northwind has this same structure: a compound key (Order, Product) and small pay load (quantity, price).

There is probably another way to tell EF not to treat this as many-to-many without adding a dummy property. I just don't remember what that is.

Comment: I tried to add somme dummy properties on my LinkedTransport table but nothing changed: still the same problem. Thanks anyway.

Comment: I strongly suspect that you have an EF configuration issue, not a Breeze issue. As I said, the Northwind `OrderDetail` entity has the same fundamental structure as the type you're trying to create. I suggest that you make sure you're getting the expected result on the server and then over the wire. Then I'd look at what the metadata say about this entity.

Comment: Thanks to your question update, it appears the issue is on the client side. When you set a breakpoint immediately after adding the `linkedTransport` and check the value of `transport.linkedTransports()`, is the new entity present? If so, there may be an event timing race condition ... for which I can make a suggestion.

Comment: I updated my question (UPDATE 2) to show the values immediately after adding the `linkedTransports`. I hope this can help.

Comment: Can you confirm also at that point that the transport with id=5 is also already in cache? Breeze doesn't do a lazy load. I realize your expand would have retrieved related transports ... known at the time of the query. But in this case you're creating a new link. If that new link references a related transport that isn't in cache ... the breeze client won't fetch it automatically. If (as I hope), transport-with-id-5 is not in cache, that would explain why it shows up later when you issue the query again.

Comment: As you said transport with id 5 is not in cache and that's the source of the problem. My idea now is to try to load the transport 5 immediately before or after the creation (linkedTransport) and hope that breeze will do the match and relations.

Comment: As said in my previous comment, I tried to load transport id 5 immediately before or after the creation (linkedTransports) but unfortunately I still get null for the related entity (transportRelated). I also tried to load both (main) transport 1 and (related) transport 5 in the activate event and still get null. Is it normal in this cas? I should have succeed, shouldn't I?

Comment: Ok finally I got it working! I'll post here soon details about my implementation (thanks to Ward recommandations).